# Retrieving two matches from repeated pattern

Tags: text-processing, grep, awk

How can I retrieve matches from two repeated patterns: `mappedname` & its value in the text below?.

```
MapName:abc
someDiffName=someDiffValue
x=3
y=6
NeedyMappedName=NeedyMappedValue
.
.
Flag=true
```

---

```
grep "MapName\|NeedyMappedName" fileName
```

If I run `awk` on the `grep` output, it will apply to each line so won't give the expected result.

The output I would like to get is

```
abc,NeedyMappedValue
```

If I run `grep "MapName\|NeedyMappedName" fileName`' it will give me the required two lines. And when I extract the required values with `awk -F ":" '{print $2}'` it will give `abc` & I won't be able to extract the second required match, `NeedyMappedValue` from the filtered grep output. Is there any way to achieve this by running `awk` with some pattern with a different pattern for second line?

Comment: Please clarify what you are asking, especially the awk part and fix "repeatitavie".

Comment: Once I run 'grep "MapName\|NeedyMappedName" fileName' will give me required two lines. And when I extarct required values with awk -F ":" '{print $2}' will give abc & I won't be able to extract required NeedyMappedValue from filtered grep output. Is there any way to achieve this by running awk with some pattern & awk with different pattern for second line

Comment: I provided above comment & I have received correct answer as can be seen below. Let me know if I need to edit query to be more specific

Comment: I edited your question. It should be reopened.

Comment: you could pipe grep's output through sed to transform the `=` to a `:` (or vice-versa), then you would have the same field separator for both lines.

Comment: @CraigSanders indeed, or even simpler, use a multiple character field separator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that's what you expect:

```
grep "MapName\|NeedyMappedName" fileName | awk -F: '
/MapName/ {printf "%s,",$2}
/NeedyMappedName/ {gsub("NeedyMappedName=","");printf "%s\n",$1}'
```

Edit: removing the unnecessary grep (thanks to Craig Sanders)

```
 awk -F: '
/MapName/ {printf "%s,",$2}
/NeedyMappedName/ {gsub("NeedyMappedName=","");printf "%s\n",$1}' fileName
```

and going a little further with awk (nawk on Solaris):

```
awk FS=":|=" '
/MapName/ {printf "%s,",$2}
/NeedyMappedName/ {printf "%s\n",$2}' fileName
```

Comment: the first grep isn't needed any more - awk is already ignoring all but the matching lines.

Comment: @CraigSanders You are right, I overlook the redundancy. Thanks.